# Como obtener valores de checkBox dinamico en el controlador ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, checkbox

Hice una vista que relaciona el rol del usuario con el usuario, creo la vista con las casillas de verificación dinámicas que puede registrar roles y luego asignarlo al usuario, solo cuando envío los roles marcados, en el controlador no se retornar al controlador , me marca nulo, estas son mis clases.

```
public class CheckBoxClass
{
    public string Nombre_ChB { get; set; }
    public bool Value_Check { get; set; }
    public int Id_Check { get; set; }
    public string IdUsuario { get; set; }
}


public class CheckBoxList
{
  public List<CheckBoxClass> CheckBoxLista { get; set; }
}


    public ActionResult ListaCheckVistaParcial(string ID)
    {
        using (var db = new ProductoEntities())
        {
            var q= db.USUARIO_INTERFACEMTY.Where(x => x.USERID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

            return View(ListaCheckBox(q));
        }


 public List<CheckBoxList> ListaCheckBox(USUARIO_INTERFACEMTY usuario)
    {
        List<CheckBoxList> listaChB = new List<CheckBoxList>();
        List<CheckBoxClass> lcbc = new List<CheckBoxClass>();
        CheckBoxClass lb;

        using (var db = new ProductoEntities())
        {
            foreach (ROL_ACCESO r in db.ROL_ACCESO)
            {
                lb = new CheckBoxClass();
                lb.Id_Check = Convert.ToInt32(r.ID);
                lb.Nombre_ChB = r.NOMBRE_ROL;
                lb.Value_Check = false;
                lb.IdUsuario = usuario.USERID;
                lcbc.Add(lb);
                listaChB.Add(new CheckBoxList() { CheckBoxLista = lcbc });
            };
        }

        return listaChB;
    }


[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ListaCheckVistaParcial(CheckBoxList cb)
    {

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
    }
```

```html
@model IEnumerable< InterfaceMonterrey.Models.CheckBoxList>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ListaCheckVistaParcial";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>ListaCheckVistaParcial</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Asignar Rol</h4>
        <hr />
 
        @{
            int i = 0;
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            if(i <= Model.Count())
            {
                <div class="form-group">
                @Html.Label(item.CheckBoxLista[i].Nombre_ChB, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.CheckBoxLista[i].Value_Check)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => item.CheckBoxLista[i].Value_Check, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                i++;
            } 
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. ¿esto es Razor?, si es así, te sugiero investigar cómo asignarles el evento `onclick` a los CheckBox.

Comment: si es con razor, al momento de ya enviar la info en el controlador , no recibo nada como los CB son dinamicos ni la lista me aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando generas los checkbox se generan de la siguiente manera:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="Value_Check"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="" name="Value_Check" />
//...
```

Como notaras todos se generan con el mismo nombre. Si en el controlador buscas el valor Value_Check notaras como te returnara el valor del ultimo check seleccionado:

```
//...
public PartialView ListaCheckVistaParcial(CheckboxList list)
{
   string value = Request["Value_Check"];
  //...
}
//..
```

Para poder enviar multiples valores con el mismo nombre, tienes que indicar el nombre como si fuera un array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Value_Check[]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="Value_Check[]" />
```

En tu caso seria:

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.CheckBoxLista[i].Value_Check, attributes: new { name = "Value_Check[]"})
```

Entonces el action separas a los valores ya que se envían separados por coma:

```
//...
public PartialView ListaCheckVistaParcial(CheckboxList list)
{
   string[] values = Request["Value_Check[]"].Split(',');
  //...
}
//..
```

`Request["Value_Check[]"]` te retornara los valores de los checkbox seleccionado. Por ejemplo si seleccionas 3 checkbox, te retornara: `True, True, True`.

Dicho esto, es obvio que tendrás problemas para poder identificar cual valor pertenece a que checkbox por lo que tendrás que inventar un mecanismo para identificar que valor pertenece a que checkbox.